# management of browser autofill functionality (Node / Express / Jade App)

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, pug, autofill

The application I'm developing for a client needs to be deployed but not public.

So there is a login page just to get into the homepage, which then has the basic options for login, register &c.  These are completely separate authorisation regimes.  Both require passwords and usernames, but the outer one has no need of flexibility or automation; I simply hard-coded the user/password criteria into the application as an object and will remove that module when going public.

I've explained this to the client, and I don't think it's confusing, but the browsers' autofill functionality can't tell them apart.   The browsers attempt to autofill the inner login form fields with the input from the outer one.

Is there any way to tag them as distinct objects?

Answer (score 0):

Going to go out on a limb (past my aoe) and say that this kind of feature would have to be implemented by the browser builders at the browser lever, and possibly the HTML protocol level.